# linking hpp and cpp issues with g++ compiler

Tags: c++, oop, g++

I am relatively new to c++ and have a solid C and Object Oriented background. So I have the following code written.
I have `Person.hpp` which is as follows:

```cpp
class Person
{
    private:
        struct h
        {
            char *name;
            unsigned char age;
        };
        struct h entities;
    public:
        unsigned char age();
        char *name();
        Person(char *name, unsigned char a);
        ~Person();
};
```

The `Person.cpp` looks as follows:

```cpp
#include "Person.hpp"


char *Person::name()
{
    return entities.name;
}

unsigned char Person::age()
{
    return entities.age;
}

Person::Person(char *name, unsigned char a)
{
    entities.name = name;
    entities.age = a;
}
```

And finally `main.cpp` looks like the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Person.hpp"

int main()
{
    Person someone("something", 100);
    printf("%s is %d old\n", someone.name(), someone.age());
    return 0;
}
```

I am already aware of the warning that it will cause due to the fact that the string is not constant. This will not cause an error when trying to compile. I tried compiling the code in two different methods. One by just compiling all together which would look like the following:

```
g++ -o main main.cpp Person.cpp
```

And the second method I tried was to compile them into object files and then link them together:

```
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c Person.cpp
g++ -o main main.o Person.o
```

They both give the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x5b): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to `Person::~Person()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem but it dissapeared when I started using CLion

Comment: What made you declare `~Person()` in the first place? Why not remove it and let the implicitly defined one take over?

Comment: Don’t edit your question to make the problem go away. Adding the missing destructor invalidates the answers you’ve gotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a destructor declared here in your header file:

```cpp
public:
   unsigned char age();
   char *name();
   Person(char *name, unsigned char a);
   ~Person();   // <===== Declared here
```

But you haven't provided any definitions for it.

However, the destructor is called after your `main` function returns (you can learn more about this behavior [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)), so it needs a definition.

You can make the compiler generate the definition for you by either omitting the destructor declaration or use `~Person() = default`.

Comment: Yes. I just tried it; however, this did not change anything sadly :(

Comment: Make sure you recompile the object files and relink them. Looks like the code works after the suggested modification: https://godbolt.org/z/76Y1Ee

Comment: @AnonymousGuy Yes it changed your error message.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried compiling object files again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declare both an constructor and `destructor` in `Person.hpp`, but only define the constructor in the `Person.cpp` file.

Try add the following code to `Person.cpp`:

```
Person::~Person()
{
}
```

Comment: I tried doing it as suggested before; however this did not change anything

Comment: @AnonymousGuy Yes it changed your error message.

Comment: Clean all .o files and recompile Person.cpp

Comment: Have you tried cleaning up your old object files before the rebuild?